# Why is a DOM click event taking so long?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

[image]

Clicking my button is taking >2s, before my code is reached (the code in the actual button handler runs in ~10ms).

It's bound as follows:

```
$('#my-div').find('.my-button').on('click', function(){ ... })
```

No other mouse event handlers are bound to this element or its parents or children.

There are a lot of these buttons, about a thousand on the page. I'm guessing that has something to do with it, but I still don't understand why it's quite so slow. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: @keja Is this different? Why would this work?

Comment: was a reply to the other comment, that is now deleted. so i also removed mine. - i havent used jQuery in a long long time, so im not 100% sure if there is any difference.

Comment: @keja We seem to be in a deletion cascade! I'm trying it out now, will let you know if it makes a difference!

Comment: I would suggest you actually do try the `$('#my-div').on('click', '.my-button'...` approach.  That will set one event handler, which the button clicks will propagate up to, as opposed to a thousand for each individual button.  Good chance that makes a difference.

Comment: Could you try to use: `$('#my-div').delegate('.my-button', 'click', function(){ ... })`

Comment: @SlavaFominII `delegate()` is deprecated, the `on()` with a selector does the same thing

Comment: @JosiahKeller Good to know, thanks. I'm not using jQuery for quite some time. They should add a big red box to the documentation to make it clear. Just wanted to suggest to use event delegation strategy.

Comment: @JosiahKeller I'm afraid that hasn't made any difference.

Comment: @user31415629 Mind editing in your new code?  Not sure I'll be able to help right now but hopefully that will make it easier for someone else to answer

Comment: The problem is your html. If you save your page to disk, how much physical space does it use?

Comment: @bastos.sergio The HTML is 1.6MB

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @bastos.sergio Chrome and Firefox both have the pause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have a thousand buttons on your page, when a few dozen should be more than enough for most users. This is an accessibility problem for most users.
2. Your page is around 1.6MBs. The bigger a page gets, the slower the browser can render and manipulate it. Most programmers think that a page is slow because of javascript, actually 99% of the time the reason the page is slow is because the browser has to render and manipulate the html in the page. This is especially true for older versions of Internet Explorer.
3. You should set only one event handler, instead of setting up a thousand event handlers (which will have to be individually compiled by the browser)...

like so:

```
$('#my-div').on('click', '.my-button', function(){ ... })
```